# creating new column in excel based on conditions from two columns

Tags: excel, if-statement, match

[image: this is what it looks like right now]

[image: this is what I want it to look like]

What formulas can I use in excel to compute column D while simultaneously matching on column A,B and C.

If the case id is the same and date is the same, then if status is approved, final status is approved. but if case id is same date is same, and if status is denied, then final status is partial denial.

Can someone please help?

I tried do if and statement but I don't know how to match on unique case IDs in the same column.

Answer (score 1):

It appears there is some missing information in your query. Let me write it out similar to an Excel IF statement:

```
=IF(CaseSame,IF(DateSame,IF(APPR,Appr,IF(DENY,PtDeny,??)),??),??)
```

With the information given, we don't know what to do in all outcomes. The outcomes marked with "??" will show as FALSE, because there is no output given for those criteria. But that formula would look like this:

```
=IF(A2=OFFSET(A2,-1,0),IF(B2=OFFSET(B2,-1,0),IF(C2="APPROVED","Approved",IF(C2="DENIED","Partial Denial",FALSE)),FALSE),FALSE)
```

And even there, I'm having to make the assumptions that you intend to go off the data in the row above for "case ID is the same" and "date is the same".

Are we supposed to assume that if no other criteria is given, to use column C's answer? In that case, there is still one unknown outcome in the IF statement:

```
=IF(C2="APPROVED","Approved",IF(C2="DENIED","Partial Denial",FALSE))
```

As long as no other entry is made in Column C, that should provide consistent results.

Here are what the two statements render in the Final Status column:

[Results of both IF statements against your data and instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj2gQ.png)

I hope this helps. With clearer information what to do in all circumstances, I may be able to provide a better answer.

Comment: hi i think i see where my information is missing. if its approved then final status is approved. but if the case id and date is different and status is denied, then final status is denied. however if i have two same case Ids with same dates and one status is approved and one is denied , then the final status will be approved and partial denied.

so the if statement 2 is almost there but not every single denied statement will map to partial denial. thats my bad, i did not include allthe possible scenarios